# Water resevoir has a hole. Water boils out

Tags: water

My water resevoir has a hole in it, the vehicle does not overheat, but the water boils out like an eruption. will replacing the resevoir correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, fitting a new reservoir will enable the system to run at the correct pressure.

Make sure you use the correct antifreeze in the correct ratio for the car and season.